# How to make <hr> full width of page irrespective of the parent

Tags: html, css

How do I make the `<hr>` width 100% of the screen, not its parent?

### CSS

```
#abc {
  width: 700px;
}

hr {
  width: 100%;
}
```

### HTML

```
<div id="abc">adsasd<hr></div>
```

Comment: `100%` is a relative measure, "100% of the container's size". Since your `<hr>` has `#abc` as its parent, it'll be 100% of #abc's size. If you want something bigger, then move the `<hr>` outside of `#abc`.

Comment: You can monkey with the [positioning](http://jsfiddle.net/ujbbh5va/), but I would bet you'd need to monkey with the markup too. Probably one-half dozen...

Comment: Better still, try and avoid using `<hr />` it has no semantic meaning and is purely for style,. I haven't used an `<hr>` tag since the late '90s. Look at using `border-top` or `border-bottom` instead on an appropriate section or `div`

Comment: @JonP that would have been an excellent idea. But its like this. <div id = "main"><div id = "menu"> <hr> buttons <hr></div></div> and main has width: 800px;

Comment: I havent used HTML, CSS in quite a while so I thought I was doing something wrong so I didn't mention in the question that that div itself is included in another div @JonP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do it the way that you have it structured. You need the `<hr>` outside of that container that has a fixed width. Otherwise 100% width of the `<hr>` will be relative of its parent, not the page. Try

```
<div id="abc">
  adsasd
</div>
<!-- put the hr on its own -->
<hr>
<div id="def">
  asdfghjkl
</div>
```

Another thing that you can do is to enclose the content in a container with that width, but not the div containing the content and the hr.

```
<div id="row"><!-- use a class that takes up all the width of the page -->
  <div class="has-width">adsasd</div> <!-- create a class with a width-->
  <hr>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If it was me, I'd refactor the markup to something like:

```
<div id="menu">
    <div class="buttons">Buttons</div>
</div>
<div id="main">
    Main
</div>
```

and use CSS for the horizontal lines:

```
#menu 
{
    width:100%;
    border-top:solid 1px black;
    border-bottom:solid 1px black;    
}

#menu .buttons, #main
{    
    width:400px;
    margin:0 auto;
}

#menu .buttons
{    
    background-color:#F00;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tjt0kppb/)